# How to sum condition in array List<class> ? Unity C#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript

How to sum condition in array List with class ?

For example :

I have this class :

***productMerchant.cs***

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class productMerchant {
    public int productID;
    public string productName;
    public int qty;
    public int price;
    public int have;

    public productMerchant (int productid, string productname, int qtyx, int pricex, int havex) {
        this.productID = productid;
        this.productName = productname;
        this.qty = qtyx;
        this.price = pricex;
        this.have = havex;
    }
}
```

and i have this :

```
public List<productMerchant> productMargaretSell = new List<productMerchant> ();
```

**So how to sum condition like sum < productMargaretSell.qty > which < productMargaretSell.productID = 10 > for example.**

If there is 3 producID = 10 with qty = 2, 3, 1

So in array All productID = 10 qty will sum. And the result must be :

productID = 10 (qty = 6)

Without using Looping to check the productID if same and then sum it.

**Because using looping if data is too many it will make it lag.**

Maybe there are some function build in from unity c# can do it ?

*Like this productMargaretSell.Sum () ?*

Thanks

Comment: I kind of sounds like you would be interested in Dictionaries: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be easily done with linq.

```
List<productMerchant> result = productMargaretSell
    .GroupBy(l => l.productID)
    .Select(cl => new productMerchant
            {
                productID = cl.First().productID,
                productName= cl.First().productName,
                qty= cl.Sum(c => c.qty).ToString(),
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is GroupBy

```
public class productMerchant
    {
        public int productID { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public int qty { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public int have { get; set; }

        public productMerchant(int productid, string productname, int qtyx, int pricex, int havex)
        {
            this.productID = productid;
            this.productName = productname;
            this.qty = qtyx;
            this.price = pricex;
            this.have = havex;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<productMerchant> productMerchants = new List<productMerchant>();
        productMerchants.Add(new productMerchant(10, "A", 1, 0, 0));
        productMerchants.Add(new productMerchant(10, "A", 2, 0, 0));
        productMerchants.Add(new productMerchant(10, "A", 3, 0, 0));

        productMerchants.Add(new productMerchant(11, "B", 4, 0, 0));
        productMerchants.Add(new productMerchant(11, "B", 5, 0, 0));
        productMerchants.Add(new productMerchant(11, "B", 6, 0, 0));

        //foreach (var productMerchant in productMerchants)
        //    Console.WriteLine(productMerchant.productName + " - " + productMerchant.productID + " - " + productMerchant.qty);

        var results = productMerchants.GroupBy(g => g.productID)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                id = x.Key,
                sum = x.Sum(s => s.qty)
            });

        foreach (var result in results)
            Console.WriteLine(result.id + " - " + result.sum);

    }
```